# Replace characters in java string

Tags: java, replace

I am trying to replace the following text in some HTML:

[merchant]

I tried to use `myString = myString.replace("\\[merchant\\]", "newText");`

The string is not being replaced. Any ideas?

Comment: What does _That isn't working_ mean?

Comment: The String is not being replaced

Comment: Please show us the string.

Comment: Also, what does `replace` do?

Comment: returns a new string that replaces all instances of the first parameter in this string with the second parameter.

Comment: I guess I should have realized there wasn't a need to escape the braces since I'm looking for a literal string, and not a character that needs to be escaped by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` doesnt use a regular expression. Just use

```
myString = myString.replace("[merchant]", "newText");
```

Comment: I will accept your answer momentarily, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
    String myString = "My Sampel String [merchant]. Another line with [merchant]";
    myString = myString.replace("[merchant]", "newText");

    System.out.println(myString);
```

You don't have to use `\\` here.

Answer (score 1):

[`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) uses string literals, not regexes, so you shouldn't escape any special characters like `[` or `]`:

```
myString = myString.replace("[merchant]", "newText");
```